# Hibernate - Solving multiple queries issue

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Good morning everyone, I'd like to ask you all a question about how Hibernate behaves about inner object references and, consecutively, JOIN queries when fetching such entities.

I have a set of entities that are organised in the following way:

Entity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT")
public class Event extends CommonEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "TIME_SLOT_ID")
private TimeSlot timeSlot;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_ID")
private Room room;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "TRACK_ID")
private Track track;

(...)
```

Room.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROOM")
public class Room extends CommonEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "VENUE_ID")
private Venue venue;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
private String name;

(...)
```

Venue.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VENUE")
public class Venue extends CommonEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 60)
private String name;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "VENUE_TYPE_ID")
private VenueType venueType;

(...)
```

VenueType.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VENUE_TYPE")
public class VenueType extends CommonEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
private String name;

(...)
```

As you guys can see, I've tried to use `@Fetch` at most of the places to avoid the `N + 1 problem`, and checked other questions on SO as well. The resulting query is always something like that:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    this_.id as id1_0_6_,
    this_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT2_0_6_,
    this_.EVENT_TYPE_ID as EVENT_TY6_0_6_,
    this_.MINIMUM_SIZE as MINIMUM_3_0_6_,
    this_.NAME as NAME4_0_6_,
    this_.ROOM_ID as ROOM_ID7_0_6_,
    this_.TAGS as TAGS5_0_6_,
    this_.TIME_SLOT_ID as TIME_SLO8_0_6_,
    this_.TRACK_ID as TRACK_ID9_0_6_,
    eventtype2_.id as id1_1_0_,
    eventtype2_.NAME as NAME2_1_0_,
    room3_.id as id1_2_1_,
    room3_.NAME as NAME2_2_1_,
    room3_.SIZE as SIZE3_2_1_,
    room3_.VENUE_ID as VENUE_ID4_2_1_,
    roomfacili4_.ROOM_ID as ROOM_ID1_2_8_,
    roomfacili5_.id as ROOM_FAC2_4_8_,
    roomfacili5_.id as id1_3_2_,
    roomfacili5_.AMOUNT as AMOUNT2_3_2_,
    roomfacili5_.NAME as NAME3_3_2_,
    roomfacili5_.SERIAL_ID as SERIAL_I4_3_2_,
    venue6_.id as id1_10_3_,
    venue6_.ADDRESS as ADDRESS2_10_3_,
    venue6_.COUNTRY as COUNTRY3_10_3_,
    venue6_.NAME as NAME4_10_3_,
    venue6_.POSTCODE as POSTCODE5_10_3_,
    venue6_.TOWN as TOWN6_10_3_,
    venue6_.VENUE_TYPE_ID as VENUE_TY7_10_3_,
    timeslot7_.id as id1_5_4_,
    timeslot7_.ENDING_DATE as ENDING_D2_5_4_,
    timeslot7_.STARTING_DATE as STARTING3_5_4_,
    track8_.id as id1_6_5_,
    track8_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT2_6_5_,
    track8_.NAME as NAME3_6_5_ 
from
    EVENT this_ 
inner join
    EVENT_TYPE eventtype2_ 
        on this_.EVENT_TYPE_ID=eventtype2_.id 
inner join
    ROOM room3_ 
        on this_.ROOM_ID=room3_.id 
left outer join
    ROOM_ROOM_FACILITY roomfacili4_ 
        on room3_.id=roomfacili4_.ROOM_ID 
left outer join
    ROOM_FACILITY roomfacili5_ 
        on roomfacili4_.ROOM_FACILITY_ID=roomfacili5_.id 
left outer join
    VENUE venue6_ 
        on room3_.VENUE_ID=venue6_.id 
inner join
    TIME_SLOT timeslot7_ 
        on this_.TIME_SLOT_ID=timeslot7_.id 
inner join
    TRACK track8_ 
        on this_.TRACK_ID=track8_.id
```

with, depending where I leave the `@Fetch` annotation, sometimes even making a second query to the `VenueType` entity. Which still leads to Spring building a VenueType page instead of an Event page, when accessing `/event` URL.

The real problem is when I try to fetch my entity Event (accessing `/event` URL) from the DB, I want to show the results in the screen. But Spring opens another set of pages because of multiple querying (Likewise the JSP file from `VenueType`, as it was queried later).

If I change any of those referenced objects to Lazy fetching (e.g., "room" attribute in `Event`), then the Lazy-fetched object JSP is loaded instead (in this example, the `Room` JSP file).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your attention.

**EDIT**: I'm using the Criteria API to create the queries in this case, instead of straight JPQL / HQL.

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoters would care about explaining the reasons for downvoting. Oh well.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Mostly I try to fetch my entity Event from the DB and I want to show the results in the screen. But Spring opens another set of pages because of multiple querying. Will add that into the question, thanks.